# How do I append text to existing text file?

Tags: kotlin

When saving the text file it is being saved for example in the `Documents/` folder. I'm aware of that I need to use append to add new line of text to that existing file but I am not entirely sure how and where to add this line of code and check that file exists.

This is the current code that is handling saving the file.

```
    ...
    save.setOnClickListener {
       saveFile()
    }
  }

 private fun saveFile() {

        val fileIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT).apply {
            addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
            type = "text/plain"
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "measurements.txt")
            // Optionally, specify a URI for the directory that should be opened in
            // the system file picker before your app creates the document.
            //putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, pickerInitialUri)
        }

        saveLauncher.launch(fileIntent)
    }

    private var saveLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->

        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val uri = result.data?.data
            try {
                val outputStream = uri?.let { contentResolver.openOutputStream(it) }
                outputStream?.write(getMeasurement?.toByteArray())
                outputStream?.close()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error is ${e.localizedMessage}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does it replace the contents tho? And how does it know if its the same file?

Comment: Sorry, deleted my comment to write an actual answer, just a minute. I oversimplified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a Writer to append text. Also, you should not put your `close` call inside the `try` block, or it could get skipped and you won't release the file. `close` should go in a `finally` block, but it's easier to use `use { }` instead.

When you open an output stream from the content resolver, you can specify write and append mode by passing `"wa"` as the second argument. See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#openOutputStream(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String)) and [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ParcelFileDescriptor#parseMode(java.lang.String)) in the documentation.

`openOutputStream` throws an exception if the file doesn't already exist. If you want to create a file if it doesn't exist yet, you'll need to add that logic.

I like to exit early from a function rather than nest everything in an if-statement, so I rearranged it that way in my example, but you don't have to do that.

```
private var saveLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
    val uri = result.data?.data
    val content = getMeasurement
    if (result.resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK || uri == null || content == null) {
        return@registerForActivityResult
    }
    try {
        contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri, "wa")
            .writer().use { it.write(content) }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error is ${e.localizedMessage}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. That worked wonders. I was wondering what do I need to add so it could add linebreak?